# Pandas combine two column into a json keyValue column

Tags: python, pandas

**Hi**,

I want to combine two columns in my dataframe into a new column which is a JSON keyValue. Currently i have used itertuples(), its taking lots of time, look for a better approach. Below is my scenario, i am combining dob & data to form result column dob is the key and data is the value.

```
fn = ('Mike', 'Dorothee')
dob = ('1985-08-07', '1987-01-33')
data = ({'rank':'5', 'subject':'science'}, {'rank':'1', 'subject':'arts'})

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(fn, dob, data)), columns =['fn', 'dob', 'data']) 

for row in df.itertuples():
    df.loc[row.Index, 'result'] = str(dict([(row.dob, row.data)]))

+----------+------------+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| fn       | dob        | data                                | result                                              |
|----------+------------+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------|
| Mike     | 1985-08-07 | {'rank': '5', 'subject': 'science'} | {'1985-08-07': {'rank': '5', 'subject': 'science'}} |
| Dorothee | 1987-01-33 | {'rank': '1', 'subject': 'arts'}    | {'1987-01-33': {'rank': '1', 'subject': 'arts'}}    |
+----------+------------+-------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks @deadshot. I will accept yours as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.apply()`

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda x: {x.dob: x.data}, axis=1)
```